# How to sign in directly from link?

Tags: javascript, php, html

How may i able to signin the account from 'Test Link' by providing  Username and Password. So once test link clicked then we are already  logged in.

eg-
`<a  href="https://www.usps.com/"> Test Link </a>`

Answer (score 0):

You should never include username nor password in an URL. Instead use some hash value as token, e.g.

```
https://www.usps.com/?token=b1b512c41be3a1c0913079374abde031
```

Use this token to compare it to some credentials or session saved in your database, use the credentials to initiate the login procedure or use the session and reopen it (depends on your site).

Answer (score 0):

Token is an option. But the user is supposed to sign in at your website before. So that you could generate a token, storing at 2 palaces, server side and client site. Server site could be session or database. Client site could be cookie.

Suppose all that have been done, when user reach your site again, you could check his token from cookie, comparing with the token in your server site. So you could do the authentication.